# Difference between USER_INDEXES and USER_IND_COLUMNS

Tags: oracle, indexing

What would be the difference between using `USER_INDEXES` and `USER_IND_COLUMNS` in retrieving indexing information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One describes the index itself, and the other describes the columns in that index.  You need both to get the full picture.

Answer (score 3):

USER_INDEXES is information about the index itself;

USER_IND_COLUMNS is information about the columns (or expressions) that the index consists of.

Comment: There is also `user_ind_expressions` with functional indexes (expressions)